# Symfony failed to load some dependencies

Tags: php, symfony4

I have a few problems loading `use_cases` in my project using symfony dependency injection.

The following code belongs to `RegisterUserController` class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Infrastructure\Controller\User;

use App\Application\UseCase\User\RegisterUserUseCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class RegisterUserController
 *
 * @package App\Infrastructure\Controller\User
 * @author  Ismael Moral <jastertdc@gmail.com>
 */
final class RegisterUserController
{
    /**
     * @var RegisterUserUseCase
     */
    protected $registerUserUseCase;

    /**
     * RegisterUserController constructor.
     *
     * @param RegisterUserUseCase $registerUserUseCase
     */
    public function __construct(
        RegisterUserUseCase $registerUserUseCase
    ) {
        $this->registerUserUseCase = $registerUserUseCase;
    }
}
```

This is my `services.yml` where I have defined all the services in my project.

```
parameters:
  databaseWriterDsn: '%env(DB_WRITER_DSN)%'
  databaseWriterUsername: '%env(DB_WRITER_USERNAME)%'
  databaseWriterPassword: '%env(DB_WRITER_PASSWORD)%'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: false      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: false # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

PdoWriter:
  class: PDO
  arguments: ['%databaseWriterDsn%', '%databaseWriterUsername%', '%databaseWriterPassword%']

MysqlPdoUserWriterRepository:
  class: App\Infrastructure\Repository\User\MysqlPdoUserWriterRepository
  arguments: ['@PdoWriter']

PasswordFactory:
  class: App\Infrastructure\Factory\User\PasswordFactory
  arguments: []

UsernameFactory:
  class: App\Infrastructure\Factory\User\UsernameFactory
  arguments: []

UuidFactory:
  class: App\Shared\Infrastructure\UuidFactory
  arguments: []

UserFactory:
  class: App\Infrastructure\Factory\User\UserFactory
  arguments: ['@UuidFactory', '@UsernameFactory', '@PasswordFactory']

RegisterUserUseCase:
  class: App\Application\UseCase\User\RegisterUserUseCase
  arguments: ['@MysqlPdoUserWriterRepository', '@UserFactory']

RegisterUserController:
  class: App\Infrastructure\Controller\User\RegisterUserController
  arguments: ['@RegisterUserUseCase']
  tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

This is the error I get when I'm trying to do a curl request to `/user/register/`.

```
Controller "App\Infrastructure\Controller\User\RegisterUserController" has required constructor arguments and does not exist in the container. Did you forget to define such a service?
```

If I changed the controller definition using this, I can get it to work. So I have to specificate fullnamespace for controller definition.

```
App\Infrastructure\Controller\User\RegisterUserController:
    class: App\Infrastructure\Controller\User\RegisterUserController
    arguments: ['@RegisterUserUseCase']
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Comment: Could you show RegisterUserController's constructor?

Comment: @marv255 yes, of course.

Comment: are all services definition aligned under the `services:` key? want to be sure that you don't miss some indentation there

Comment: @Federkun Yes all the services are defined in `services.yml` file.

Comment: I mean, is `PdoWriter` etc. under the `services:` key, or are you missing four spaces?

Comment: Did you clear the cache ?

Comment: @Federkun all the services are under `services` directive and are perfectlly idented.

Comment: @codeneuss I removed all the files in cache directory, and I still got the same error.

Comment: Plz add the output of the command `debug:container` to your question

Comment: I guess `RegisterUserController` is removed because it's not used by any other services? Can you add the `public: true` flag under RegisterUserController?

Comment: @Federkun I added `public: true` and I still get the same error.